# Upload an image to a label when a button clicked in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label

I'm building a GUI using tkinter(python 3) which every user should be able to click a button and open a file dialog, Then select an image. And the selected image get displayed on a label.

I have tried numerous possible code but I still can't get it.

Comment: What did you try? Show us that

Comment: Also post the error message if there is one